# Best way to arrange data in a csv for multiline chart in d3 that has categories

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to create a time series line chart that will have multiple lines. Each of these lines will belong to a category- which has its own color. All of the examples I've found only have one header column. My data is currently formatted to have two:

```
                   Company1    Company1    Company2    Company2
    date           User1       User2       User3       User4
    17-Jun-14      10          12          5           8        
    .
    .
    .
```

Question: How do would you read the first line of a csv as the category, the second as the user, and the rest as the variable with d3?

OR, does the data need to be stacked in a format like:

```
Company      User    Date        Value
Company1     User1   17-Jun-14   10
Company1     User2   17-Jun-14   12
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d3 `parse` method only expects one row, and uses that row to create attributes.

The alternative is to use the `parseRows` method, which expects no headers and formats everything as arrays. With `parseRows`, your parsed data would look like this:

```
[
 [ '',         'Company1', 'Company1', ...]
 ['date',      'User1', ...               ]
 ['17-Jun-14', 10, ...                    ]
 ...
]
```

From there, you could iterate through your data starting on the second row, referencing the first two rows to determine company and user.